# Vue converts input[type=number] to a string value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm running into the problem, that Vue converts the value of an input field of type number into a string and I just can't figure out why. The guide I am following along does not run into this issue and get's the values as numbers, as expected.

The vue docs state, that Vue would convert the value to a number, if the type of the input is number.

The code is originated from a component, but I adjusted it to run in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d5wLsnvp/3/

```
<template>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    {{ stock.name }}
                    <small>(Price: {{ stock.price }})</small>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" v-model="quantity"/>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" @click="buyStock">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['stock'],
        data() {
            return {
                quantity: 0 // Init with 0 stays a number
            };
        },
        methods: {
            buyStock() {
                const order = {
                    stockId: this.stock.id,
                    stockPrice: this.stock.price,
                    quantity: this.quantity
                };
                console.log(order);
                this.quantity = 0; // Reset to 0 is a number
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The quantity value is the issue.
It is initialized with 0 and when I just press the "Buy" button, the console shows:

```
Object { stockId: 1, stockPrice: 110, quantity: 0 }
```

But as soon as I change the value by either using the spinners or just type in  a new value, the console will show:

```
Object { stockId: 1, stockPrice: 110, quantity: "1" }
```

Tested with Firefox 59.0.2 and Chrome 65.0.3325.181. Both state that they are up to date. I actually also tried it in Microsoft Edge, with the same result.

So what am I missing here? Why is Vue not converting the value to a number?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You need to use [`.number` modifier for `v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number), like this:

```
<input v-model.number="quantity" type="number">
```

Note: empty string (`''`) is not converted to a number, so you may need to handle it separately.

Comment: As a note, I found it by simply googling [vue v-model number input]. It's the top result.

Comment: Hm, well, yes, it works, and I feel kind of dumb now...
My searches returned several threads on github and co about the same issue without any solution, but that link was not in it... also it seems that the guide I am using is outdated... anyways, thanks for the help

Comment: I can't tell if and when it used to work. It may be that Vue 1.0 worked differently. And don't worry too much about unsuccessful googling, it happens to everyone. I added the comment more for the reference, so you can see what phrase worked here.

Comment: excellent answer! the only one I could find in the internet, that works! :) thanks +1

Comment: Is there anyway to achieve this without the use of v-model? ie when using vuex?

Comment: @chuuke Well, if you are not using v-model, then you can just use parseFloat explicitly.

Comment: Problem with this is that if the input is an empty string, it is still an empty string. So the conversion is not always accurate.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Interesting. I added a note in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Change the order object to :

```
const order = {
    stockId: this.stock.id,
    stockPrice: this.stock.price,
    quantity: +this.quantity
};
```

This will automatically parse the string to a number.

In general the data from HTML inputs are strings. The input type only checks if a valid string has been provided in the field.