# Vue model bind as a number

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am using a `v-model` on an input box, and I would like to bind using a number, but it doesn't seem to work. What is happening when I use the input box is that it saves the item as a string, and I know this because when I do `myModel += 25`, instead of `100` going to `125`, it goes to `10025`.

Is there anyway to make the input bind as a number?

This is what my input element looks like:

```html
    <input type="text" list="zoom-amount" v-model="project.zoom" />
    <datalist id="zoom-amount">
      <option>25</option>
      <option>50</option>
      <option>100</option>
      <option>150</option>
      <option>200</option>
    </datalist>
```

```js
@Component
export default class WorkspaceStatusBar extends Vue {
  @Provide() public project: Project = this.activeProject

  public get activeProject() {
    return this.$store.getters['project/getActiveProject']
  }

  @Watch('activeProject')
  public onActiveProjectChanged(newProject: Project) {
    this.project = newProject
  }

}
```

Comment: `<input type="number" list="zoom-amount" v-model="project.zoom">`?

Comment: Using a `type="number"` seems to be doing the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, just tested it out. Sorry, should have done so before commenting

Comment: Actually... I take that back... seems to be working now...

Comment: Wow, really? In my test, it a) was still a string, and b) didn't use the data-list

Comment: I think that when it wasn't working I had data list values of `25%`, `50%`, etc. which is why I used a text.

Comment: Also see [Vue converts input\[type=number\] to a string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748596/vue-converts-inputtype-number-to-a-string-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the Typescript / class-based API (so you may have to translate a little) but one approach would be to use a [computed property with both *getter* and *setter*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) where the *setter* handles the transformation to a number

```js
computed: {
  zoom: {
    get () {
      return this.project.zoom
    },
    set (zoom) {
      this.project.zoom = Number(zoom) // or parseInt(zoom, 10)
      // you can even commit / dispatch here, ie
      // this.$store.commit(...)
    }
  }
}
```

and bind your input to the computed property

```html
<input v-model="zoom" list="zoom-amount">
```

---

Here's what I think the class-style component would look like. Could be wrong but you get the idea

```
public get zoom (): string {
  return this.project.zoom.toString()
}

public set zoom (zoom: string) {
  this.project.zoom = Number(zoom)
}
```

Comment: That works! I modified the typescript getter/setter though.

Answer (score 3):

Use v-model.number="project.zoom"

Comment: Will this still allow my to input text into the field? I would like to bind the value as a number to the property, but display the value as a percentage in the textbox, so the property would be `100`, and the textbox value would be `100%`. Is this possible with this method?