# Why Vue <select v-model="number | string" > both work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Please see this minimum example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      valueIsString: '1',
      valueIsNumber: 1,
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <select v-model="valueIsString">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>

      <select v-model="valueIsNumber">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

I have two different `<select>`, one is binding to `string`, the other is binding to `number`.

**They both work, why is this happening?**

Why Vue knows mapping my number to a string?

Comment: I don't think it's vue but html. Input in html treats all values as strings, no numeric values etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this should be a result of using JavaScript. If you don`t declare the type exactly, JS allows you a lot.

So if you know that you want the input type to be an integer, you can simply add a `.number` modifier after your v-model:

```html
<select v-model.number="valueIsNumber">
```

you can [learn here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748596/vue-converts-inputtype-number-to-a-string-value) a little bit more